# Chrome developer tools, what is capture full size screenshot?

Tags: html, iphone, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I realize that there is this `Capture full size screenshot` on chrome developer mode. After trying out the features i've notice that there will a slight change of UI design after taking the screenshot (the screenshot seem wider than the viewport i saw).

I have screenshot the screen with iphone 6/7/8 device.

May I know **what is the difference of 'Capture full size screenshot' and 'Capture screenshot'** and why are the screenshots are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Capture screenshot:**

This will take screenshot of what is in the visible viewport i.e. what you can see on screen.

**Capture full size screenshot:**

This will take screenshot of whole page i.e. if the page is scrollable and there is some content which you can not see currently that will also be captured.

Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Jordan, may i know why certain div looks longer in 'full size screenshot' and it looks normal in 'capture screenshot'?
also the margin seems to scale smaller in 'full size screenshot'

Comment: @JackyLim I don't know how you have implemented your UI. There could be many reasons i.e. could be bug in `full size screenshot` or your UI implementation is not as per the `full size screenshot`. But my answer is about *what is the difference of 'Capture full size screenshot' and 'Capture screenshot'..* Thanks for your understanding.